# Yahtzee 3 of a Kind

Tags: algorithm, lazarus, turbo-pascal

Here is my situation, i am currently creating a [Yahtzee game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Rules_overview) using Turbo Pascal Language in Lazarus IDE and i am up to the scoring side of the developement, i have already completed the Lower section of scoring and i have started the Higher section but i need some help writting a procedure to check for a three of a kind, my initial thought was to use an array and load the random numbers for the dice values and then use a loop function to check for 3 equal numbers but i'm not very confident in this area. Could i get some help ? I'm not asking for code, although it would be helpful, just a push in the right direction.

My dice integer value variables are, "Dice1" , "Dice2" , "Dice3" , "Dice4" , "Dice5" , "Dice6"

Answer (score 3):

I think the conceptually simplest approach is to have an array of six counters - one for each possible value - that you initialize to zero and then loop over your dice array and increment the counters with each die's value.

You can then check if any of the counts becomes 3 (or more).

Answer (score 3):

Or sort and then iterate to see if  you have 3 same values in a row. The sorted array with dice values is also usable for the other detections like street, Carré (four of a kind), Yathzee etc.